# How to save more than 1 record into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a *for loop* which goes like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
    $sender_id = $updateArray["result"][$i]["message"]["from"]["id"];
    $sender_fname = $updateArray["result"][$i]["message"]["from"]["first_name"];
    $sender_lname = $updateArray["result"][$i]["message"]["from"]["last_name"];
    $sender_uname = $updateArray["result"][$i]["message"]["from"]["username"];
    $sender_msg   = $updateArray["result"][$i]["message"]["text"];
    // sender id
    if(!(in_array($sender_id, $sender_ids))){
        $sender_ids[] = $sender_id;
        // $sender_infos = $sender_id + $sender_fname + $sender_lname + $sender_msg + $sender_msg;
    }else{
        $key1 = array_search($sender_id, $sender_ids); // continue
    }
}
```

All I did was grabbing some information about the sender and store them in two separated arrays called `sender_ids[]` and `sender_infos[]`.

But as you can see in the code I have commented this line:

```
// $sender_infos = $sender_id + $sender_fname + $sender_lname + $sender_msg + $sender_msg;
```

Basically I want to store more than 1 index into `$sender_infos[]` array here but I don't how can I do that...

So please if you know how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Use a foreach? [PHP: foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Could you show us a hypothetical array for the result you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use `for()` loop instead use `foreach()` loop, and declare `$sender_ids` and `$sender_infos` outside the loop, and you should declare and use `$sender_infos` as an array, like this:

```
$sender_infos = [];
$sender_ids = [];
foreach($updateArray["result"] as $message){
    $sender_id = $message["message"]["from"]["id"];
    $sender_fname = $message["message"]["from"]["first_name"];
    $sender_lname = $message["message"]["from"]["last_name"];
    $sender_uname = $message["message"]["from"]["username"];
    $sender_msg   = $message["message"]["text"];
    // sender id
    if(!(in_array($sender_id, $sender_ids))){
        $sender_ids[] = $sender_id;
        $sender_infos[] = [
            $sender_id,
            $sender_fname,
            $sender_lname,
            $sender_msg,
        ];
    }else{
        $key1 = array_search($sender_id, $sender_ids); // continue
    }
}
```

Or to use `$sender_infos` as an associative array instead:

```
$sender_infos[] = [
    'sender_id' => $sender_id,
    'sender_fname' => $sender_fname,
    'sender_lname' => $sender_lname,
    'sender_msg' => $sender_msg,
];
```

Answer (score 4):

Create another array for sender_infos

```
$sender_infos[] = [$sender_id,$sender_fname,$sender_lname,$sender_msg];
```

you will be able to access infos like `$sender_infos[0]`

or an associated array

```
$sender_infos[] = ['sender_id'=>$sender_id,'sender_fname'=>$sender_fname,'sender_lname'=>$sender_lname,'sender_msg'=>$sender_msg];
```

you will be able to access infos like `$sender_infos["sender_id"]`